# Vim: how to limit the left cursor movement to the first non-whitespace character of the line?

Tags: vim, padding, vi

Is there a vim setting that restricts the cursor movement only to the leftmost non-whitespace character of the line?

I am writing a plugin that is outputing some information to a buffer. All the text is going to have a lot of whitespace padding on the left, but all the lines will be indented the same. I would like to prevent the user from moving the cursor on this padding area where there is no text.

For example:

```
|    Lorem ipsum
|    Lorem ipsum
|    Lorem ipsum
|    Lorem ipsum
```

The '|' represents the vim border, and between the border and the text are whitespaces. The cursor should never be moved on these whitespaces and should stop on the 'L'.

Comment: I guess the user will be smart enough to use **w** in those cases.

Comment: We need more information on what you are trying to accomplish. For instance can we prevent the buffer from being changed via `''nomodifiable'`? If so you can just store your extra information about each line in a buffer-local variable. Maybe we can use conceal. Maybe this shouldn't be a buffer, but instead use the quickfix list or `inputlist()`.

Comment: I already prevent the buffer from being changed and it needs to be buffer. Not sure what more information to provide...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the cursor to the beginning of the line with `CursorMoved` and `:normal!`

```
augroup BossyMotions
  autocmd!
  autocmd CursorMoved <buffer> if strpart(getline('.'), 0, col('.')) =~ '^\s*$' | execute 'normal! ^' | endif
augroup END
```

For more help see:

```
:h :normal
:h :autocmd
:h :autocmd-buflocal
:h :augroup
:h CursorMoved
:h :exe
:h strpart()
```

Comment: I think my question was misunderstood... I want to prevent cursor movement to the left when the cursor is on the first non-whitespace character of the line. All the lines are prefixed with a lot of whitespace (using the python lib for vim). I am basically trying to create a padding effect without too much hassle.

Comment: I have added this to my vimrc, but I don't see any difference... is there more to it?

Comment: This is a a buffer local `autocmd` (aka `<buffer>`) you need to add this to a specific buffer. Basically you can move however you want to with this but if you end up inside the indention it will force you to the first non-blank character.

Comment: ah it works, I tested it with a regular txt file, I guess for other files various plugins had their own 'autocmd!' reset. If my plugin creates a buffer of type `.foobar` how can I bundle this command only for this type of buffers?

Comment: `autocmd! CursorMoved *.foobar if strpart(getline('.'), 0, col('.')) =~ '^\s*$' | execute 'normal! ^' | endif`